# jQuery: Selecting an item in a drop down list using key (Symfony)

Tags: jquery, symfony, select

I have an array of choices with a key associated with each choice. Now I need to use the **key** to select an item from a drop down.

if i use the following code, what it will do is select the item with index `someval` but the thing is I need to select an item depending on the **key** and not the index .

```
$('select').val('someval')
```

here's my array:

```
'choices' => array(
    'A' => '0',
    'B' => '1',
    'C' => '3',
    'D' => '4',
    'E' => '7',
    'F' => '10',
)
```

As you can notice, the key doesn't match the index or otherwise this wouldn't have been a problem. It's only the key that have been stored in database and not the index, that's why I have only the key to use to select an item from the drop down. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

my project is in Symfony; and the `choices` array is found in the formbuilder. I am using jQuery to fill data on the form

Comment: I can't figure out what you're talking about. There's no key in a `<select>`. `.val('someval')` doesn't use the index, it looks for `<option value="someval">`

Comment: And your array looks like PHP, not Javascript. What does that have to do with choosing an option from a menu?

Comment: @Barmar in fact my project is in Symfony, I am going to update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$('#yourselect').val(['".implode("','", array_keys($yourarray))."'])";
```

generates JS:
$('#yourselect').val(['A','B','C','D']); // etc...

Comment: can you explain your answer a little bit please?